# need help parsing shell script command line arguments

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Unix shell scripting and would like some help with writing small script.

I have defined a following synopsis for my script:

```
install.sh [-h|-a path|[-k path][-f path][-d path][-e path]]
```

ie user can request some `help (-h)`, install all to a specified place (`-a path`), or install one or more of a components (`-k, -f, -d -e`) to a appropriate paths. If there is no arguments, the help should be shown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getopts` to parse a command line with `bash`. Here is an example taken from [Bash/Parsing command line arguments using getopts](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Bash/Parsing_command_line_arguments_using_getopts) (obviously you'd have to adjust the options to your needs).

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set a default value for the $cell variable
cell="test"

#Check to see if at least one argument was specified
if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
   echo "You must specify at least 1 argument."
   exit 1
fi

#Process the arguments
while getopts c:hin: opt
do
   case "$opt" in
      c) cell=$OPTARG;;
      h) usage;;
      i) info="yes"
      n) name=$OPTARG;;
      \?) usage;;
   esac
done
```

Related SO question [How do I parse command line arguments in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)?

For more information search for `getopts` on this [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for bash.